# Computing TCP checksum in python

Tags: python, network-programming

I came across this peice of code [here](http://www.binarytides.com/raw-socket-programming-in-python-linux/): to compute checksum.
As far as I understand in order to segregate the binary data structure into 16 bit words as required for TCP checksum:
 I recon the value of w should be dirieved as `w= ord(msg[i]) << 8 + ord(msg[i+1])` unless, the byte order has to be changed. I am not too sure as to why w would be assigned value as `w = ord(msg[i]) + ord(msg[i+1]) << 8`. Is there anything specific I am missing here?

```
def checksum(msg):
  s = 0
  # loop taking 2 characters at a time
  for i in range(0, len(msg), 2):
    w = ord(msg[i]) + (ord(msg[i+1]) << 8 )
    s = s + w

    s = (s>>16) + (s & 0xffff);
    s = s + (s >> 16);

    #complement and mask to 4 byte short
    s = ~s & 0xffff

    return s
```

Comment: pls remove `>` symbols present  at the start of your code. Then selct all the code block then press ctrl + k . It should do the code formatting for u.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Do you know what big-endian (first case) and little-endian (second case) mean?

Comment: Avinash; thanks did that @Punchia: yup I do. The msg is in network order

Comment: @Punchia:  yup I do understand. what i mean to ask is : if I have  a string '\x01\x02' -> would translate to 258 if w = (ord('\x01')<<8) + ord('\x02\) which equals to 0000000100000010( which i expected to be the case) why would we shift the '\x02' instead of '\x01'( which the author actually did in the example code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I think "network order", "big endian" and "little endian" are being mixed with the TCP Checksum calculation.

The TCP Checksum calculation is defined in RFC 1071: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1071

At the beginning of page 2:

> > Using the notation [a,b] for the 16-bit integer a*256+b, where a and b are bytes,

The bytes in the Pseudo Header and partially filled TCP Header are just "bytes" and no implication is made as to what they mean (they must already be in "network order")

The formula used by the author is just following RFC 1071

Comment: Thank you very much. I refered to the RFC and it states checksum calculation is independent of byte order - on page 3    Byte Order Independence

        The sum of 16-bit integers can be computed in either byte order.
       ... the sum may be calculated in exactly the same way
        regardless of the byte order ("big-endian" or "little-endian")
        of the underlaying hardware.